# Cronjob using command WGET throws error forbidden

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, cron, wget

I have a cronjob that will run every day at a specific time with command something like `wget -O- "https://www.replaced-with-example-domain.com/cron/export-all-files" >> /dev/null` which is creating an excel file and upload in the server.

The command above resulting `ERROR 403: Forbidden`

The url `/cron/export-all-files` is pointing to a blank page (no authentication) with only jquery inside to access another url (also no authentication)

**The view page (export.php)**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
const baseUrl = "https://www.replaced-with-example-domain.com/";

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: `${baseUrl}sales/invoice-list/export`,
        data: {
            'export': true,
            'cron': true
        },
        success: function(res){
            console.log(res)
        }
    })
})
</script>
```

If I run the url (in command) manually in the browser, it can be executed without any issue but when running with cronjob it will throw error forbidden.

If I add `--user-agent="Mozilla"` (refer to [this](https://bobcares.com/blog/wget-403-forbidden/)) in the cron command it will give this output

```
--2022-06-05 12:16:01--  https://www.replaced-with-example-domain.com/cron/export-all-files
Resolving www.replaced-with-example-domain.com (www.replaced-with-example-domain.com)... xxx.x.xxx.17
Connecting to www.replaced-with-example-domain.com (www.replaced-with-example-domain.com)|xxx.x.xxx.17|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 488 [text/html]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

     0K                                                       100% 70.1M=0s

2022-06-05 12:16:01 (70.1 MB/s) - written to stdout [488/488]
```

But no excel file created and uploaded so I am wondering if it's actually working. What is the correct way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: As far as I can tell WGET does not execute javascipt, it does not act as a browser. Also, all your Javascript seems to to is call another page. Why not call that other page directly, if you can change those POST parameters.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Hi thank you for your reply. I did as what you said and changed my command to `wget --user-agent="Mozilla" -O- --post-data "export=true&cron=true" "https://www.replaced-with-example-domain.com/sales/invoice-list/export" >> /dev/null` and it's working fine now. Thank you!

Comment: Ah, you can post parameters with WGET, yes, that should work. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

> The url `/cron/export-all-files` is pointing to a blank page (no
> authentication) with only jquery inside to access another url (also no
> authentication)

Wget does not support JavaScript execution and therefore jQuery. If you need to get effects of executing JavaScript on page you need to use different tool, for example [PhantomJS](https://phantomjs.org/). You would need first to install it. For your needs following should suffice

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://www.example.com', function(status) {
  console.log("Status: " + status);
  phantom.exit();
});
```

it does simply open `http://www.example.com` output status and exit. Change address to your needs and save above as `loadpage.js` then use it as `phantomjs loadpage.js`.